# How to find the value of $ 81^{1/\log_53} + 27^{\log_9{36}} + 3^{4/ \log_79}$?

Tags: logarithms

The question seems easy but is not. I tried making bases as 3 but log is in power and base of log too is different.

Comment: Thanks for giving the formatting a shot, but you still have some errors. Please match up the braces and check the backslashes.

Comment: What is wrong I ain't getting

Comment: I gave it a shot. Did I guess right?

Comment: Yes I am not getting answer when I tried to take power of $3^4$ as 81 can you help

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Hint. $\log_b x = \log_a x/\log_a b$

Comment: Hint: $\frac 1{\log_5 3}=\log_3 5$ and so on.

Comment: Ethan can you tell me what a here means

Comment: Ethan's hint means $\log_7 9 = = \frac {\log_3 9}{\log_3 7}$.    Or $\log_5 3 = \frac {\log_3 3}{\log_3 5} = \frac 1{\log_35}$ which leads directly to lulu's hint.

Comment: I would offer a third hint. $\log_{a^k} b = \frac {\log_a b}{\log_a a^k} = \frac {\log_a b}{k} = \log_a b^{\frac 1k}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bear in mind $\log_a b = \frac 1{\log_b a}$ and $\log_{a^k} b  = \log_{a}b^{\frac 1k}$.

So $81^{1/\log_53} + 27^{\log_9{36}} + 3^{4/ \log_79}=$

$(3^4)^{\log_3 5} + (3^3)^{\log_{3^2}6^2} + 3^{4\log_{3^2} 7}=$

$(3^{\log_3 5})^4 + (3^{\log_3 6})^3 + (3^{\log_3 \sqrt 7})^4$

And from there you just finish it.

$5^4 + 6^3 + \sqrt{7}^4 =5^4 + 6^2 + 7^2$

$625 + 8*27 + 49$

$=.... $.

Well, heck, I don't do addition.